# Why do I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'def playerMove():'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's my code:

```
Board=['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
def printBoard():
  print Board[0:3]
  print Board[3:6]
  print Board[6:9]
printBoard()
def playerMove():
    counter=0
    for i in range(9):
        move=int(raw_input('What spot would you like to move? 0-8'))
        counter+=1
        if(counter%2==1):
            Board[move]='x'
        else:
            Board[move]='o'

playerMove()
```

I am new to python, so please don't change my code to make it better or more efficient, just tell me what I need to do to change the value resulting from the input to an integer. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see how that error is possible with this code. Make sure this is in fact the code you're running, and double check the error. You would have to somehow be reading the source file itself to get an error like that.

Comment: You may want to not use `'0'` as filler, it is very hard to read (when you're playing).

Comment: Are you giving source code to `raw_input`?

Comment: Please copy and paste the *entire* traceback as part of the answer. It will help those trying to help you better understand the nature of the error.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code and it appears to be running fine. I get that same error when I attempt to do something other than an int, like 1.2. Is that not intentional?